# Angular perform REST petition

Tags: angular, rest, get

I'm trying to perform a GET using Angular, but it is not working.

I have a component that injects a custom service on constructor, this service performs the rest petition and store the result on array.

Following is `bird.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface Bird {
  id: number;
  bird_name: string;
  bird_image: string;
  bird_sightings: string;
  mine: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class BirdService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     this.getBirds().subscribe(data => this.birds = data);
  }

  birds: Bird[];

  getBirds() {
    return this.http.get('http://dev.contanimacion.com/birds/public/getBirds/1');
  }

}
```

Following is `bird.page.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BirdService } from '../bird.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-birds',
  templateUrl: './birds.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./birds.page.scss'],
})

export class BirdsPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public birdService: BirdService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And finally on `bird.page.html`

```
<ion-content>
  <div *ngFor="let bird of birdService.birds"></div>
</ion-content>
```

I obtain the following errors:

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/bird.service.ts(16,40): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Bird[]'.
[ng] The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
[ng] src/app/bird.service.ts(16,40): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Bird[]'.
[ng] The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
[ng] Property 'length' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

Comment: I see a few issues. 1. you're never subscribing to the observable returned by the HTTP rest. As such the request is never being triggered. if you were to look at the network tab in dev tools, do you see the request going gout?

You can either subscribe to the service in the BirdPage.ts component file. or you can use the 'async' pipe in the template.  doing so will automatically subscribe to the service for you.

Changing your class to something like this.birds = this.birdservice.getBirds().  Then in your template doing *ngFor="let bird of birds | async" should get you what you need.

Comment: @Edward 
First subscription is in the service constructor and if you add `| async ` and use an `*ngIf` around it, it will call too much times the service.
It's more like a transpilation error.
Did you try `this.http.get<Bird[]>('http://dev.contanimacion.com/birds/public/getBirds/1')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below two approach

One option would be , you can add async keyword to subscribe the observable

```
<div *ngFor="let bird of birdService.getBirds()|async"></div>
```

Observables are lazy which means without subscribe , it won't initiate the call or emitting , when you use async keyword angular will automatically subscribe for you.

You can also manually subscribe like below.

```
constructor(private birdService: BirdService) { }
  birds:Bird[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.birdService.getBirds().subscribe((res)=>{
   this.birds=res;
     });
  }

<div *ngFor="let bird of birdService.birds"></div>
```

Suggested the first approach because it will also unsubsribe the observable  when the component destroy.

Also not recommended to subscribe on the service constructor , keep your view model on the component always.